# Issue on setting a UIImage to a custom UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a `UIViewController` that has two properties: a `UIImageView` and a `UiButton`. They are both `IBOutlets` properly connected on the `Interface Builder`. My problem is that when i instantiate this view and set both properties only the `UIImageView` is set. My `UIButton` is a `custom` button and I'm trying to assign an `UIImage` to it. This is my code:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[viewController view];

viewController.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

viewController.myButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
```

any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
viewController.myButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
```

with

```
[viewController.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

should work

Comment: That totally did it! Thanks a lot =]

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if you need to use a particular method to set the image of an UIButton instead of accessing the setter of the property. That method is:

```
[viewController.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Or some other variant of UIControlState such as UIControlStateSelected, UIControlStateDisabled, UIControlStateHighlighted, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how u set an image for a button, you should use

```
[viewController.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```